# jQuery return false from function

Tags: jquery, function, preventdefault

sorry for my english ...
I would like to advise how to stop a function from another function using e.preventDefault() or something else. I simplified the code for understanding. My code is here:

```
 function websControlYear(){
     var year = 2020;
     if(year == 2020){
          return true;
     }else{
          return false;
     }
 }

 $("#div").click(function(){
      websControlYear()
      //if true code runnig, if false return alert("wrong value")
 });
```

Comment: `if (websControlYear()) { alert("failed"); return; }` will return from the click event handler and not continue with the rest of the code.   preventDefault is to stop a default action from happening, eg if `#div` is an `<a>` then it would redirect to the anchor href, unless you preventDefault.

Comment: #div is button. If the function $("#div").click(function(){... is true then I still have the ajax function but your solution did not work for me

Comment: What "ajax function"?  `$("#div").click(function` won't ever return "true".  Perhaps you've over simplified the code and it now makes no sense / or is just *inverted*.  If you have code currently running, like a a loop, you can't stop that code as javascript is single threaded.  If you have an ajax call then you can abort the ajax call/ignore its result - or other asynchronous call will likely require a flag within the async call to indicate it's been "stopped".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.